Documentary About Jean Seberg
So, I remember watching a very strange documentary about the actress Jean Seberg a few years back. I think it was from the '80s or '90s, judging by the style, though it's possible that it came out later. (Definitely not earlier than the '80s, because it came out after Seberg died in 1979, and had several references to her death.) 
The whole gimmick was that they had another actress playing Jean Seberg - not in a biopic sort of way, but in a weird "(faux) Jean Seberg narrating her own life" kind of way (made even stranger by the actress/faux-Jean Seberg's casual references to "After my death..." or "When I died..."). I remember I got a very "'90s TV show/documentary for kids" vibe from it, though I'm not sure that said vibe was intentional. I can also recall some very odd transitions between found footage and the narrator (e.g. I think at one point they showed a clip of (the real) Jean Seberg during a scene in front of a mirror from Breathless, and then they overlayed the fake Jean Seberg's face into the mirror as she started to narrate).
I'm pretty sure the narration was in English, though some of the found footage and clips from Jean Seberg movies were obviously in French.
Does this ring a bell for anybody?

Have you looked at the "in popular culture" section of her wiki page? There's several films listed there...

Thanks! I hadn't seen that section of her Wiki page, and it did help me find the right documentary!

Great! You should go ahead and answer your own question, then :)

Okay, thanks to Catija pointing me to a part of Seberg's wiki page that I hadn't noticed, I was able to find the title: From the Journals of Jean Seberg. To quote imdb's summary:

Mark Rappaport's creative bio-pic about actress Jean Seberg is
  presented in a first-person, autobiographical format (with Seberg
  played by Mary Beth Hurt). He seamlessly interweaves cinema, politics,
  American society and culture, and film theory to inform, entertain,
  and move the viewer. Seberg's many marriages, as well as her film
  roles, are discussed extensively. Her involvement with the Black
  Panther Movement and subsequent investigation by the FBI is covered.
  Notably, details of French New Wave cinema, Russian Expressionist
  (silent) films, and the careers of Jane Fonda, Vanessa Redgrave, and
  Clint Eastwood are also intensively examined. Much of the film is
  based on conjecture, but Rappaport encourages viewers to re-examine
  their ideas about women in film with this thought-provoking picture.

Not sure I'd agree with the editorialized bits of that summary, but it nonetheless matches what I remember seeing!
